# NodeMCU 1.0 compiler gives error: File Exists on Arduino IDE 1.8.X

Tags: compiler-errors, esp8266, nodemcu

I suddenly get a new compiler error on previously compiled code. In fact, all NodeMCU1.0 examples generate this same error.
**"C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar: unable to rename 'C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_410489\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\ESP8266WiFi.a'; reason: File exists"**
I thought it might be the new IDE 1.8.10 so I rolled back to 1.8.9 but no help.
I used board manager to remove and reinstall the NodeMCU/ESP8266 libraries 2.5.2 from Github but no help.
I went to appdata\Arduino15 and temp\various and deleted everything that could safely be deleted and again reinstalled libraries but no help.
The weird thing is this apparent archive file with the .a extension cannot be found anywhere and I checked to be sure the cache was empty.
Until this is solved my NodeMCU makes a very poor paperweight. :-)
Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to comment on your question, so please excuse this short answer:

Try running the Arduino IDE in administrator mode, and compile your code. You could change compatibility settings for the Arduino executable and make it always run as administrator, as a more permanent workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Please check ESP8266 firmware version and set/upgrade/downgrade to version 2.4.2. it will work

Comment: Hey Thanks! That did it! It now compiles with 2.4.2. Looks like something went wrong with the 2.5.0 build because I tried that and it again failed. So I'm sticking with 2.4.2.